# Docker PostgreSQL image

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to create a postgresql image using docker for my db. For some reason it doesn't create my new Database or anything.

When I try to run my container I receive this:

````
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604283300Z ***************************
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604288900Z APPLICATION FAILED TO START
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604293000Z ***************************
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604297200Z 
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604301200Z Description:
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604305400Z 
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604309400Z Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604313700Z 
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604317400Z Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604322700Z 
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604326800Z 
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604346700Z Action:
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604351000Z 
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604355000Z Consider the following:
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604359200Z  If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
2022-09-04T18:07:11.604363500Z  If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).```
````

but my application properties looks like this:

```
server.port=8091

#liquibase properties
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=db/changelog/db.changelog-root.xml
spring.liquibase.defaultSchema=activities_schema

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/random-activities-db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I am trying to do this in a SpringBoot application.

Also:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:latest
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

docker-compose:

```
services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=random-activities-db
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

Later edit:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450200700Z 2022-09-04 18:51:23.449 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450267900Z 
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450280700Z org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450287700Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450292500Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450296500Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450300700Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450305200Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450309600Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450314400Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450318600Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450324800Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450330000Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450334400Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450351200Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450357000Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450361800Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450366100Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450371100Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450375400Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450379500Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450383500Z  at com.John.random_activity.RandomActivityApplication.main(RandomActivityApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450387300Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450391400Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450395800Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[application.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450400000Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[application.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450403900Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[application.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450408200Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[application.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450411300Z Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450414900Z  at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:271) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450418300Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450421700Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450425300Z  ... 24 common frames omitted
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450428600Z Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450437400Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:319) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450443100Z  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450459300Z  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450463600Z  at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450467200Z  at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450470600Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450474300Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450477700Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450480700Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450483700Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450488100Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450491900Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450495600Z  at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:266) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450499100Z  ... 26 common frames omitted
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450503000Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450507000Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450510500Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450514100Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:539) ~[na:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450517900Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:594) ~[na:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450521600Z  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450525700Z  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450529300Z  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450533000Z  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450537100Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450559100Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar!/:42.3.6]
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450563800Z  ... 38 common frames omitted
2022-09-04T18:51:23.450568100Z
```

Now it starts but I receive this. I verified if the port is open: is open and listening on postgres.

Comment: `Failed to determine a suitable driver class` - did you include postgresql driver into target jar?

Comment: You are trying to connect to localhost, but that is not where the db runs.

Comment: When I just try to run the application I can see the changes in PgAdmin, but I receive this```org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
 ```

Comment: The Docker still not works as expected as in my post

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your infrastructure is the link between the db service and the spring service.

By default, when running containers, **each one has its "proper network"**. It means that the container is not reachable from outside (except exposed ports) and not reachable from other containers. That means, in the current context, **your spring container and your database container cannot communicate between each other**

Hopefully, there is a solution to link your containers to make them interact with each others => **Docker Networks** (see [this page for more informations about them](https://docs.docker.com/network/)). Docker-compose can manage these networks and links for you very simply by providing the `links` array in your `docker-compose.yml`

[Have a look at the docker-compose documentation on networking!](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Your `docker-compose.yml` should now look like this:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  spring:
    build: . # Or image: yourimage:version
    restart: always
    links: # Specify the links with another containers
      - db # Make the db container reachable from this container through hostname "db"
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=random-activities-db
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

Now that your `docker-compose.yml` is properly configured, you can access the database container from the `db` hostname in your spring container. That means you have to change your application.properties from this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/random-activities-db
```

to this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/random-activities-db
```

Also, I suggest you to use environment variables ([placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties) in Spring) to specify database-related stuff:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}/${DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

Your docker-compose spring container configuration should now look like this:

```
services:
  spring:
    build: . # Or image: yourimage:version
    restart: always
    links: # Specify the links with another containers
      - db # Make the db container reachable from this container through hostname "db"
    environment: # System environment reachable via ${KEY} in Spring
      - "DB_HOST=db:5432"
      - DB_NAME=random-activities-db
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
```

And that's it!